# Why is $2^n$ so important in deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network

While initializing and training a deep learning model we often use some quantities such as number of hidden neurons in dense neural networks, number of filter in CNNs, batch_size while training a neural network, number of units in LSTM cell, etc. are in the powers of 2 i.e. $2^n$.

Is there any specific reason to do the same?

Comment: In most case, I think it is just an habbit we have, and it isn't really useful. But since we usually like multiplying / dividing by 2 the number of neurons on consecutive layers, it stays in that $2^n$ space. One place where it actually is useful is in CNN, since convolutions divide the size of the image by 2, it is important to have an input image with height and width easily divided by 2 (256, 192 most of the time).